# Are Jews below age 20 judged the same as those above 20 on Rosh Hashanah?

Tags: rosh-hashanah-new-year, age

Are Jews below 20 judged differently then Jews above age 20? I know there is a question posted on this site whether or not punishment starts in shamayim below age 20, but I want to know specifically about the  Rosh Hashanah trial. Cite sources please. Thanks!

Comment: Why would you think those under 20 years old would be tried on Rosh HaShanah? Isn't it clear from the sources that people under 20 are not punished by Shamayim?

Comment: The midrashim say אין ב"ד של מעלה **מענשין**, specifically **punish**. Maybe there's a judgement, ie: not death or life but non punishment things like how much money they'll get. Anyways most of the sources I saw specifically applied it to kares. Health for the upcoming year might not apply. @ezra. Also most achronim I saw further limit the scope of this concept, as brought elsewhere on this site.

Comment: @robev I'll buy that. +1 to this question